# prevent function returned pointer from going out of scope?

Tags: c++

I am opening a directory with opendir (which returns dir *) and want to keep and reuse the dir constantly in my object.  I had originaly opened the directory in my constructor and stored the pointer as a private variable, this obviously failed since as soon as the constructor ended the pointer was out of scope and the memory freed.

My question is, how do I keep the directory reference so that my class can keep using it over and over without reopening it each time?  I've tried copying it to a DIR type, but I get a complaint that DIR is not fully defined.  I doubt even if I could figure out where DIR is defined it will have a copy constructor anyways.  There must be another way to keep it in scope?

Comment: To be sure that I understand:  (i) You have a type T.  (ii) You have several objects t1, t2 and t3 of this type.  (iii) All of the several objects t1, t2 and t3 are to share the same dir *.  (iv) The trouble is that, as soon as t1 reaches the end of its life, the dir is lost; whereas t2 and t3 still want to use the dir.  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: "Open directory" - this is too general. Provide more context about what you are using.

Comment: Actually thb it's simpler then that. I have a single object. I want to open a directory within that single object. Throughout that objects long life it will constantly be polling the directory for information and files; and since that is in my critical path I want to avoid the cost of re-opening the directory every time I need to poll it.  I would like to open the directory once, in my constructor, and have the directory stay open for the lifetime of that single object.  Unfortunately as soon as I reach the end of the constructor the pointer is out of scope and can no longer be used

Comment: Could you post code of what you tried?

Comment: Did you possibly declare the pointer local in the constructor as well as a member of the class? The local copy goes out of scope, with the member variable never being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way an object can go out of scope in C++ is for it to be a local variable.  I'm going to guess you did something like this:

```
Object *objMemberPointer;

Constructor()
{
    Object obj;
    objMemberPointer = &obj;
} <- obj goes out of scope here and deallocates your object.
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question.
How would I go about reassigning an array that has been passed as an argument to a function? I need to reduce the size of and change the values in the array so I'm trying to create a new array, free the previous array and memcpy the new one, but it gives an error. If I don't free the previous array, it works fine but there are some extra values from the previous array still existing at the end.

Comment: @Ali this is entirely new question.  You should create a new post for it (assuming someone else hasn't already asked it).